# XWiki AppWithinMinutes add custom velocity script on display

Tags: python-3.x, groovy, velocity, xwiki

I am new to XWiki and not a Java Developer. I would like to develop a simple AppWithinMinutes app (Let us call it ServerCatalog) for a list of servers with their properties like OS, Environment, etc.. That is all doable. I can develop that from AppWithinMinites UI.
I also have developed a macro which lists all pages by tags.

Now for example, when Someone creates an entry in my ServerCatalog say SERVER**D**56 Where **D** stands for Development environment.
when we display that Entry, I also want to execute my macro that I developed so that it can list all pages that matches the tag SERVER**X**56.
Note that I replaced **D** with **X** So before executing macro, I want to manipulate that page title and remove Environment prefix (in this case **D** for Development Environment) with **X**.

I hope it is clear of what I want to accomplish. Please let me know if it is unclear.

If someone can assist me on doing it, I will truly appreciate that.

**EDITS:**
As suggested by Eduard Moraru, I tried following things:

I have created a custom macro called "PageListByTag".
Since python has more control over string operations, I added following at the end of ServerCatalogSheet

```
.
.
.
.
{{/html}}
{{/velocity}}


{{python}}
title = document.getTitle()
newTitle = title[:6] + "X" + title[6+1:]
print(newTitle)
{{/python}}
```

There are several problems with it..

1. my html tag is already ended. I can't inject any new content in it anymore
2. I can't add python code inside velocity tags as nested scripting is not allowed by XWiki
3. I still don't know how to call my macro inside python code if I want to use python

If I can replace 6th character in a string using velocity, then everything works. I can use macro inside velocity script since it is within that html boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to **customize** the "sheet" of the application which is used when displaying an application entry.

If you have a look a the documentation's section on customization, you get a lot of starting points on where you should be looking:

https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/App%20Within%20Minutes%20Application#HCustomization

This line would be interesting (but also the above links on how XWiki applications work):

> The sheet, which is used to display and edit application entries (e.g. HolidaySheet)

In your case, it the document to customize (edit in `wiki` syntax mode) should be `ServerCatalog.Code.ServerCatalogSheet`

Inside that document, you have code automatically generated by AWM to which you can add a call to your macro.

```
## AWM generated code...
...

## Customization:
{{displayAssociatedPages /}}
```

Then, inside this macro (called `displayAssociatedPages`, in this example), you could do something like:

```
{{velocity}}
#set ($title = $doc.title)
## OR #set ($title = $doc.name), depending if your pages have titles

#if ($title.startsWith('SERVERD'))
  #set ($tag = $title.replaceFirst('SERVERD', 'SERVERX'))
  ##
  ## We can reuse and customize this snippet: https://snippets.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Display%20pages%20with%20a%20specific%20tag/
  ##
  #set ($references = $xwiki.tag.getDocumentsWithTag($tag))
  #foreach($reference in $references)
    #set ($document = $xwiki.getDocument($reference))
    #set ($label = $document.getTitle())
    [[$label>>$reference]]
  #end 
#end
{{/velocity}}
```

API documentation and more info at https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/API/

Also, you should understand that once you customize an AWM application, you should be careful when editing it with AWM itself. For example, if you add a new field, AFAIK, you risk having the customizations done to your sheet, as in the above example, overwritten, so you should recover them from document history and re-apply them.

Comment: Eduard, Thanks for your detailed response. I will try it out and keep you posted.

Comment: Eduard, I have tried it.. Now in ServerCatalogSheet document, how can I replace nth character in a string? I managed to call my custom macro and that seems to be working.. I want to replace 7th character in `$doc.title` which is environment indicator "D", "Q", "U" and "P" and replace it with "X". I can't find good documentation on it.

Comment: I Edited the post on what I have tried so far.

Comment: I ended up using `#set ($newTitle = $title.substring(0,6) + "X" + $title.substring(7, $title.length()))` and that seems to be working

Comment: Glad you got it working. Remember that Velocity works with Java objects. So if you know the type/class of your object, you can look up the Java documentation for it. In this case, it was String (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Also note that the `String.replaceFirst` method actually works with regex. So, in my example, instead of "SERVERD", you could have used "SERVER." and that should be it.

i.e.:
`$title.replaceFirst('SERVER.', 'SERVERX')`

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: Eduard, on the same line, there is one big issue.. my velocity script results seem to have cached on sheet page. So it displays cached results on unrelated pages as well. I have question open on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72707615/caching-issue-with-app-within-minutes-sheet-pages. Can you please suggest any ideas on how can I overcome this? Is there any no-cache directive that I can set.. so that it renders every time? Thanks a lot.